# Recommendation for icon editor

Tags: software-rec, editing, icons

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there an open source to edit icon ?](https://superuser.com/questions/179227/is-there-an-open-source-to-edit-icon)
>   [icon creator software](https://superuser.com/questions/33673/icon-creator-software)

I'm looking for a good freeware icon editor. Any recommendations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an open source to edit icon ?](http://superuser.com/questions/179227/is-there-an-open-source-to-edit-icon), also possible duplicate of [icon creator software](http://superuser.com/questions/33673/icon-creator-software)

Comment: The dup links no longer exist, there is however a valid answer for free software here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/795/free-offline-tool-to-create-icon-files  (spoiler: simply use GIMP, export, and give the file extension `.ico`)

Answer (score 8):

[IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/)

Comment: Damn, beat me! :)

Comment: This is no longer freeware... (You get a few week demo then it will not save.)

Answer (score 5):

I know you preferred freeware, but I have actually bought an [Axialis Icon Workshop](http://www.axialis.com/iconworkshop/) license in the past and this software is arguably the best.

Comment: Tried following their official tutorial (here: https://www.axialis.com/tutorials/make-your-own-icons.html) and it refers to options that simply don't exist. Even the hotkeys are wrong (They say press `I` to export, but that just inverses the image colours). After over an hour wasted trying to do a simple export from an existing image, I can't recommend this myself.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows icons, use [@icon sushi](http://www.towofu.net/soft/e-aicon.php) to convert to and from individual png images, and simply edit those in any modern image editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/):

> IcoFX is an award winning professional icon and cursor editor. It is
>   an all-in-one solution for icon creation, extraction and editing. It
>   is designed to work with Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and
>   Macintosh icons supporting transparency. Create Windows icons up to
>   256x256 for Windows Vista/7 and Macintosh icons up to 1024x1024 for
>   Macintosh OSX 10.7 Lion.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this program is no longer free